# How Owin Works regarding AuthenticationTicket to a authenticated UserPrincipal

Tags: owin

So, ive made a simple basic auth middleware for owin. The middleware returns an AuthenticationTicket with the user principal claims, authentication type ("Basic") yada yada.

```
protected override Task<AuthenticationTicket> AuthenticateCoreAsync()
      {
         ....
         var claimsIdentity = TryGetPrincipalFromBasicCredentials(token, Options.CredentialValidationFunction);
         ....
         var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(claimsIdentity, new AuthenticationProperties(){userName = claimsIdentity.name});
         return Task.FromResult(ticket);
      }
```

To get the claims, im using a hardcoded value for testing:

```
var claims = new List<Claim>();
         claims.Add(new Claim(KneatClaimTypes.Permission, Permission.UserAdministrationView.ToString()));
         var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(
            new GenericIdentity("Administrator", "Basic"),
            claims
         );
         return claimsIdentity;
```

I`m hooking into owin using a simple extension using the same architecture IdentityModel has
https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.Owin.BasicAuthentication

```
 app.UseBasicAuthentication(new BasicAuthOptions("Realm",
         (username, password, context) => BasicAuthCredentialCheck.Authenticate(username, password, context))
         {
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            AuthenticationType = "Basic"
         });
```

Im creating the correct principal for the ticket, but after the owin resolves the authentication the Thread.currentPrincipal is not populated. If i add a simple cookie auth , whenever i call `Owin.Authentication.SignIn(...)` it creates the Principal for me. If i set manually the Thread.currentPrincipal, something is UNSETTING that.

Im not very deep on how owin works under the hood, and i was tryng to get the source from it and begin reading it maybe ill figure it out. But in case i dont, any ideas on who could be resetting this Thread.currentPrincipal ? (Searched my own app code, no one does that, only reads no setting)

Best Regards.

Comment: CurrentPrincipal is not async friendly. You're better off getting the current user from the HttpContext or OwinContext.

Comment: but why does it work with my Cookie and OAuthBearerToken middlewares ?